# How can I set EditorWindow to be in the center of the screen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Prefab : EditorWindow
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;
    List<Transform> transformSelection = new List<Transform>();
    int transformsCount = 0;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Prefab")]
    static void CreatePrefab()
    {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow<Prefab>();
        //GetWindow<Prefab>().position = new Rect(980, 380, 322, 278);
        GetWindow<Prefab>().position = new Rect(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 322, 278);
    }
```

This put the window in the center by width but on the top of the screen.

[image: EditorWindow]

I'm not sure that even the width is in the middle. But the height is on the top.

The big white rectangle is the window.

Comment: Can you position the window with the line, you have commented out?

Comment: @PoulBak I can and it will be more or less in the center. Maybe I will stay with this uncomment line and will use it. Just wondering why using Screen / 2 is not working.

Comment: Yes, screen.height / 2 should (almost) Work. Try: (Screen.width - 322) /2 and (Screen.height - 278) / 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
    int width = 322;
    int height = 278;
    int x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
    int y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

    GetWindow<Prefab>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: I find this doesn't work on a MacBook, I'm using `EditorGUIUtility.GetMainWindowPosition().center`